# Edit code based on a string during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program in which the user types a string which the code needs to type out using the InputSimulator NuGet package.

Is there a way for me to type the code and fill in the blanks with strings and have it run? here is what it mean:

```
Inputsimulator sim = new Inputsimulator();
   sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
```

(`VK_A` Would be replaced with `"VK_" + MyLetter`)

Is there any way to change or make code to run during runtime?

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `TextEntry` method instead:

```
sim.Keyboard.TextEntry("Say hello!");
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist "SimulateTextEntry".

Comment: @Simkoo `TextEntry` should be available to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_A`, but it obviously look like an `enum`, so they must have incremental integer values, So:

```
int a = (int)WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_A;
```

would give you the value of `VK_A`, and `VK_B` would be a+1, and so on...

```
int a = (int)WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_A;
for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
   sim.Keyboard.KeyPress((WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode)(a + i));
```

You may use a method like this:
WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode KeyCode(char chr)
{
    int a = (int)WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.VK_A;
    if( a >= 'A' and a<='Z')
    return (WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode)(chr - a);
    //else do other cases 
}

And then you can use it like this:

```
sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(KeyCode('B'));
```